# Creating Instance of a Gui (Minecraft modding with ModLoader)

Tags: java, user-interface, minecraft

First off, I'm really just messing around trying to learn Java. All I want to do at this point is display a string to the screen;

So I have my mod_Bite class and my BiteGui class. (Bite is just a random name, I was eating at the time)

```
//mod_Bite.java
package net.minecraft.src;

import net.minecraft.client.Minecraft;

public class mod_Bite extends BaseMod {

    @Override
    public String getVersion() {
        return "1.0";
    }

    @Override
    public void load() {
        ModLoader.setInGameHook(this, true, true);
    }

    public mod_Bite() {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTickInGame(float tick, Minecraft mc)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

and

```
//BiteGui.java
package net.minecraft.src;
import net.minecraft.client.Minecraft;

public class BiteGui extends Gui {

    private Minecraft mc;

    public BiteGui(){
        drawBiteGui();
    }

    public void drawBiteGui() {
        FontRenderer fr = this.mc.fontRenderer;
        drawString(fr, "Testing!", 5, 5, 0xffffff);
    }
}
```

What I don't understand is how to create it. I tried creating an object of BiteGui in the onTickInGame method (even though I don't think it should create it every tick)

```
public boolean onTickInGame(float tick, Minecraft mc)
{
    BiteGui biteObj = new BiteGui();
    return true;
}
```

But it says there's a null pointer exception, which to my knowledge means that I'm trying to use something that's not been assigned any value or it's pointing at nothing.
I'm obviously not doing something right here.

---

Edit: I changed the code and it works except the text flashes with each tick instead of staying on the screen. It's obviously because I'm creating the object in the onTickInGame method but I don't know how to initialize Minecraft from anywhere else.

```
package net.minecraft.src;

import net.minecraft.client.Minecraft;

public class mod_Bite extends BaseMod {

    @Override
    public String getVersion() {
        return "1.0";
    }

    @Override
    public void load() {
        ModLoader.setInGameHook(this, true, true);
    }

    public mod_Bite() {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTickInGame(float tick, Minecraft mc)
    {
        BiteGui biteObj = new BiteGui(mc);
        return true;
    }
}
```

and

```
package net.minecraft.src;
import net.minecraft.client.Minecraft;

public class BiteGui extends Gui {

    private Minecraft mc;

    public BiteGui(Minecraft minecraft) {
        this.mc = minecraft;
        drawBiteGui();
    }

    public void drawBiteGui() {
        FontRenderer fr = this.mc.fontRenderer;
        drawString(fr, "Testing!", 5, 5, 0xffffff);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the exception? Anyway, to begin with use the Java APIs (Swing) and not try to add more clutter to the logic, leave that for later.

Comment: I'm curious as to why you're using ModLoader and not Forge.

Comment: Thanks for telling us what kind of error you got; you wouldn't believe how many people just say "It didn't work. Fix it." Nevertheless, when you get an error, please tell us the full stack trace you get. This tells us the line number and other details, which we can use to better diagnose your problem. Thank you!

Comment: Could you add what versions of Minecraft, Java and ModLoader you wrote your code to work with? And how you eventually fixed the mc == null issue; (ie showing the line of code initializing mc)?

Answer (score 2):

You don't ever initialize `mc` in your `BiteGui` class.  Then you try to refer to it in `drawBiteGui` with `this.mc.fontRenderer`.  This will give you a `NullPointerException` as you say.

```
private Minecraft mc;
```

... is equivalent to ...

```
private Minecraft mc = null;
```

You should add something in your `BiteGui` constructor to initialize it to something.

Comment: Ahh that makes sense I passed in Minecraft from onTickInGame and it works but the text flashes with each tick. How would I get the text to just stay displayed? I updated the main post with what I did.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to get it to stop blinking! In mod_Bite,

change this:

```
ModLoader.setInGameHook(this, true, true);
```

to this:

```
ModLoader.setInGameHook(this, true, false);
```